# JQuery on() delegate by element instead of string selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a method that looks a little like this:

```
function turnBlue()
{
    $(this).css('background-color','blue');
}

function fillWithGoodies(obj)
{
    var goodie_box = $("<div id='goodie_box'>Goodies!  Click me and my parent will turn blue.</div>");
    $(obj).append(goodie_box);
    $(goodie_box).on('click', obj, turnBlue);
}
```

The problem is that when turnBlue() is called, "this" is the goodie_box div, not the obj.  (I want the object)

JQuery used to have a .selector() method, but it doesn't look safe to use.  http://api.jquery.com/selector/  If it worked, I would have done:

```
    $(goodie_box).on('click', $(obj).selector(), turnBlue);
```

Is there a way to do this without changing the architecture?

*Note*: I know I could do the below instead, but my example here is just a subset of the real code.  My question is: Can you somehow get the selector of an object.

```
    // Don't want to have to do this:
    $(obj).on('click', function() { doSomething(obj) } );
```

*Note #2*: Calling parent() isn't a solution for this one: The real code creates a complex dynamic object and the parent could be at any depth.

Comment: Why `$(obj).append("<div id='goodie_box'>Goodies!</div>").on('click', doSomething);` do not works?

Comment: Oops, good point.  My example isn't correct.  Fixing..

Comment: once you fix the YD1m question it should wotk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many selectors, with uncountable possibilities for combinations of CSS classes, pseudo classes and more. I don't believe that it would be practicable to implement it. Your link also says ***...property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used...***

Further, the `selector` property is not for using like you may have understand. Have a lokk at the documentation: ***A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event***

But there is a possibility to pass data to the handler. Sample from documentation:

```
function greet(event) { alert("Hello "+event.data.name); }
$("button").on("click", { name: "Karl" }, greet);
$("button").on("click", { name: "Addy" }, greet);
```

So in your case it will look like following:

```
function turnBlue(event) {
    $(event.data).css('background-color','blue');
}

function fillWithGoodies(obj) {
    var goodie_box = $("<div id='goodie_box'>Goodies!  Click me and my parent will turn blue.</div>");
    $(obj).append(goodie_box);
    $(goodie_box).on('click', obj, turnBlue);
}
```

Comment: Yes - that's what I was looking for.  I didn't know about the event.data property.  Thanks Marvin!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
function doSomething(that)
{
    console.log(that);
}

function fillWithGoodies(obj)
{
    $(obj).append("<div id='goodie_box'>Goodies!</div>");
    $(obj).click(function(){
      doSomething(obj);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a param in `on([selector])` and it is not a selector,it will turn to `[data]`,so you can try this:

```
function turnBlue(e)
{
    $(e.data).css('background-color','blue');
}

function fillWithGoodies(obj)
{
    var goodie_box = $("<div id='goodie_box'>Goodies!  Click me and my parent will turn blue.</div>");
    $(obj).append(goodie_box);
    $(goodie_box).on('click', obj, turnBlue);
}
```

See [passing data in jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data) for more

Comment: Brilliant!  That's just what I was looking for.  Thanks Jarvan!  (It looks like Marvin beat you to the answer, though)